# Vue3 ref loses its value when page reload (Vite)

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I am assigning a value to a component ref based on a prop value, as follows:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
    tableRows: {
        type: Array,
    },
});

const localRows = ref(props.tableRows);
</script>

<template></template>
```

When saving the file, VITE reloads, and localRows has the prop value, but when reloading the page in the browser, localRows ref looses its value. Anybody has any idea what causes this phenomenon?

Thank you.

I tried to assign the value in on Mounted hook, the behaviour did not change.

Comment: How and where do you set your `:tableRows=?` prop? The code is not enough to understand the problem.

Comment: <WideTable2 :tableRows="tableRows" />. WideTable2 component has the tableRow  data all the time, whenever VITE refreshes or I reload browser page. But when I reload page, the value from prop is not "transferred" to the ref. The localRows ref will be an empty array.

Comment: I tried to rename the tableRow prop to tableRowWideTable to avoid same naming, and now it works! I do not know why, but perhaps it can help others, that it can cause such problems.

Comment: @TamásLászló naming the prop and the binded variable usually should not be a problem and renaming the prop should not have any effect. Strange that it worked out.

Comment: Today it is not working again...

Answer (score 1):

You are using `props.tableRows` as the initial value of the `localRows` ref.  Probably the props is not initialized yet with data on load (while it is on vite HMR). Also, it will not update when the prop changes, probably you might want that reactivity.

To make this work, use a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) instead:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
    tableRows: {
        type: Array,
    },
});

const localRows = computed(() => props.tableRows ) 

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working. However still not sure if it is connected to VITE or not, as in an other project, that is using webpack, the similar ref(prop.something) value assign is working in several places in the codebase.

Comment: It is working however I cannot change the value of the ref if I use computed.

Comment: Setting the initial value of a ref by a prop can indeed work and it has nothing to do with vite or webpack. In your current case however, the prop is probably `undefined` when the child is loading, thus setting the initial value or the ref to `undefined`. A computed property is monitoring the used variables in it, and when the prop gets updated, the computed function will run, returning the new value.

Comment: You can make computed properties writable with a getter and setter. See: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed But in your case, the computed property represents a prop and props should not be altered in the child. If the child has updated the value and then the parent updates the value, the changes in the child will be lost. This can cause weird and hard to find bugs in larger applications. Use emits for updating props, see: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#mutating-object-array-props

Comment: Gabe - Thanks, that was my case!